# Problem Duplicating Textures

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have a material that contains several procedural textures. I need to duplicate an object that has that texture applied, and then change one of the texture parameters in the duplicated object without changing the original. I need to do this with python but I can't even to it with the  UI. Because setting the Material option under 'Duplicate Data' allowed me to create a new instance of the material properties I thought selecting Textures would do the same, but apparently not.

So how do I and what does selecting 'Duplicate Data: Textures' in user preferences actually do? (I'm running 2.69)

File used to generate the screen shots below, below.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/234662328/Limestone_1.blend

[image]

Comment: You could do this by making a single user copy of the material, but I'm not sure why the material remained unchanged for the original when tweaking some settings. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: These are two questions. Please ask only one and create another thread for the other one.

Comment: You are comparing two different things there. The first Screenshot of the settings shows the material settings, the later one is texture settings.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Cycles Texture will not be defaultly linked by another material. The problem you met is because you put the texture in the node group, which can be shared as sort of "public datablock", while there is currently none for that in the Duplicate Data setting yet. Probably we should suggest some genius developer to improve this? lol

To solve this, just simply make a single user for the node group.

Finally back to your question: the "Material" and "Texture" checkbox there perfectly work for BI. As for Cycles, Material does work, but for the Cycles Texture, I don't think it's gonna work that way, since it needn't. As I said, Cycles texture is kind of "material-independent", unless being part of a node group, in other words, an independent datablock shared by materials.